# Why does ProFTPd stop at Entering Passive Mode on Debian on a Windows Virtualbox?

Tags: debian, ftp, virtual-machines, proftpd

I have installed Debian Squeeze on a Windows computer with Oracle Virtualbox. Then I've port forwarded port 21 on the NAT adapter.

In Debian I've run:

```
apt-get install proftpd
```

Then I uncommented the PassivePorts so I have the ports 49152 to 49155 available as passive ports. Then I uncommented MasqueradeAddress and set it to 127.0.0.1

Then after trying to Quick Connect in FileZilla I get:

```
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 FTP Server ready.
Command:    USER webserver
Response:   331 Password required for webserver
Command:    PASS *
Response:   230 User webserver logged in
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 UTF8 set to on
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,192,3).
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

How can this be fixed? It seems that it's something related to the VM, (running on the same machine right now), because all tutorials out there suppose it should work after just running the `apt-get`.

Comment: Uncomment PassivePorts from proftpd.conf, restart the server and retry.

Comment: @Sacx I have already tried this, tried with MasqueradeAddress as well. I opened the defined ports in PassivePorts on the NAT adapter in the Virtualbox settings.

Comment: @MDMarra Can I ask why this was closed as off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to enable `PassivePorst` in your `proftd.conf` -

```
   PassivePorts      35000 40000
```

Enable the `ip_conntrack_ftp` module

```
   modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
```

In your firewall, all the ports related to ftp/passive ftp have to be opened -

```
 iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 35000:40000  -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 35000:40000  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! But it didn't work, unfortunately. Same output as always..

Comment: why are you trying to access the Ubuntu vm using 127.0.0.1 rather than its IP address?

Comment: Okay, so I'm using Debian as the production server, and so I'm using Debian as the testing server. So on my WINDOWS computer, I have installed Debian on Virtualbox. I set the network adapter to NAT, and have port forwarded 80, 22, 21, 49152-49155. This way I can develop on my Windows computer and SSH into the Debian and upload the files via FTP just like it was an external server residing on it's own IP address. So when I connect to localhost:80, it will actually be redirected into the VM to Debian, same with 21 for FTP.

Comment: It turned out what you wrote is everything that should be needed. The problem was that the ports I forwarded and used (49152-49155) didn't work for some strange reason. I tried 5000 to 5003 instead, and it just magically worked. Maybe those ports were already in use, or else there has got to be something wrong with Oracle Virtualbox on these ports. Anyway, thanks for you time! I do really appreciate people like you trying to help, spending their time for others who have struggled without getting this to work!